# iconStyler for Fusion Tables (Google Maps) won't pull column data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am building a map using the Google Maps API and have hit a snag. In the table I have a column that labels the iconName for each marker ('mStyle', it's col3). In the following code I am trying to set the icon style based on the column values, and I've tried many, many different iterations that haven't worked. Including this one.

What has perplexed me, is that replacing  iconStyler:{} with iconName: 'grn_blank' (or whatever) does work. The documentation for markerOptions is here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/style

```
        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
    layer.setOptions
    (
    {
      query: 
      {
        select: "col0",
        from: "1UtgWf_kgwI3iUtrWvH3vIbxJfBdutl9oR8Wjqhiv",
        where: ""
      },
      styles: 
      [{
       markerOptions:
       { 
        iconStyler:
        {
          kind: 'fromColumn',
          columnName: 'mStyle',
        }               
       }
      }]
    }
    );
```

The code can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxeBEc_dsbUqWVJwbV9JTXRvb2s/edit?usp=sharing

The way the map should look is about 800 flags in the DC area, in various colors (red, purple, blue, green, light blue, and white). They represent schools. I can make it work in the browser-based editor, but I am adding dynamics once I get this piece to work, so I need it to work in Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Click on the map tab in the fusion tables UI, select "Publish", "Get HTML and Javascript".
In that code grab the layer definition:

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col0",
        from: "1UtgWf_kgwI3iUtrWvH3vIbxJfBdutl9oR8Wjqhiv",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
```

you want the styleId and templateId defined there (looks like 2 and 2 to me).

Comment: You saved my life, man!  Where did you get this info?  I've been looking everywhere!!!