# Google Maps API: Fusion Tables Layer: How to get the templateId and styleId configured on the table?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

`google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` accepts `templateId` and `styleId` parameters in its constructor. The question is: how to extract these values from the table itself?

The need comes from wanting to use the marker icon settings and the infowindow settings configured on the fusion table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing Info Window in FusionTableMapLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011454/customizing-info-window-in-fusiontablemaplayer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iconStyler for Fusion Tables (Google Maps) won't pull column data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264038/iconstyler-for-fusion-tables-google-maps-wont-pull-column-data)

Answer (score 3):

One can get the `templateId` and `styleId` from the fusion table by going to the *Map tab* -> *Publish* -> Look in any of the two generated urls for parameters `tmplt` (this is the `templateId`) and `y` (this is the `styleId`)

Resource: [Fusion Tables Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/gAw9dA/)

If anyone has a more elegant way to obtain these ids, please leave a comment.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs for [templates](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/template) and [styles](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/style) if you want to get at these values programmatically.

Comment: In my case, the style and template were already set on the fusion table, so they were preset so to speak.